# Comparing rown in multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays - 1 multidimensional where columns describes answers and rows - students. Second one is solution array with correct answers.
I need to write method for finding which rows has same wrong answers(some kind of anti cheat) which returns multidimensional array, where index represents student, and each sub-array lists
the indices of all students who have similar wrong answers to the student at that index.

Here is how i try to do it:
int num - represents threshold, for counting wrong answers.

```
public static int[][] findSimilarAnswers(int num,char[][] responses,char[] solutions){
    int[][] stats = new int[responses.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
        int length = numMatches(responses,solutions,i,num);
        int[] wrongs = new int[length];
        for (int j = 0; j < wrongs.length; j++) {
            wrongs[j] = numWrongSimilar(responses[i],responses[i],solutions);
        }
        stats[i] = wrongs;
    }
    return stats;
}
```

method `numWrongSimilar` compares two arrays for wrong answers and return number of wrong answers:

```
 public static int numWrongSimilar(char[]studentOneResponse,char[]studentTwoResponse,char[] solutions){
    int wrong = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < solutions.length; i++) {

            if(studentOneResponse[i] != solutions[i]
                    && studentOneResponse[i] == studentTwoResponse[i])
                wrong++;
        }

    return wrong;
}
```

and method `numMatches` find which wrong answers are higher than threshold.

Here is arrays of responses and solutions.

```
 char[][] responses = {  {'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A'},
                            {'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'},
                            {'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'},
                            {'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'}
    };      

char[] solutions = {'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'};
```

With this array and threshold `3` it must return 
`[[], [3], [], [1]]`

but it returns `[[], [3], [], [5]]`

seems like i write wrong line here `wrongs[j] = numWrongSimilar(responses[i],responses[i],solutions);`

but how should i correctly rewrite it?

Comment: Hmm... each column is a separate student? Then wouldn't the length of `solutions` be 4, since each column has 4 entries (since there are 4 rows)? Perhaps you are mixing up rows and columns. Multidimensional arrays are addressed `array[row][column]`. (rows are horizontal, columns are vertical.)

Comment: I rewrited description. Rows are students, and columns are answers

Comment: thanks, that makes more sense